# Level sets of Hamiltonians of S^1 actions

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry

Suppose that $(M,\omega)$ is a (connected compact) symplectic manifold with a Hamiltonian $S^1$-action given by Hamiltonian $H$. I would like to find a reference for the fact that  every level set of $H$ is connected. I tried to find this statement in McDuff Salamon, but could not.

Comment: This follows directly, by a standard argument, from the fact that $H$ is a Morse-Bott function, all of whose critical manifolds have even index (and co-index).

Comment: Robert, thank you for your comment! I was wondering if there is some textbook where this is written...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Michael F. Atiyah, [Convexity and commuting Hamiltonians](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=642416) (1982), Lemma 2.3.

Dusa McDuff and Dietmar Salamon, [Introduction to symplectic topology](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1698616) (2nd ed., 1998), Lemmas 5.51 and 5.54.

Michèle Audin, [Torus actions on symplectic manifolds](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2091310) (2nd ed., 2004), Corollary IV.3.2.

Comment: Thank you very much Francois, this is exactly what I needed :) (I have missed these lemmas from McDuff...)